# Sum of $k$ smallest singular values

Tags: matrices, singular-values, matrix-norms

The $k$th Ky Fan norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{(k)}$ is defined as the sum of the $k$ largest singular values. Furthermore, for an $m\times n$ matrix $A$
$$
\lVert A\rVert_{(k)} = \max_{UU^*=VV^*=I_k}|\text{tr}(UAV)|.
$$
For Hermitian matrices the sum of the $k$ smallest eigenvalues, denoted $E_k(H)$, is
$$
E_k(H) = \min_{UU^*=I_k}\text{tr}(UHU^*),
$$
so I was wondering if the sum of the $k$ smallest singular values $S_k(A)$ for a matrix $A$ can be written
$$
S_k(A) = \min_{UU^*=VV^*=I_k}|\text{tr}(UAV)|.
$$
As I have not seen this expression I thought that perhaps it is not true, and that the argument used for the two previous examples fails at some point. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Presumably you mean the **sum** of the $k$ smallest singular values

Comment: Thank you, it has been corrected.